# HTML CSS: How to align grid to content area?

Tags: html, css, grid, alignment, center

Demo: http://www.mindtale.com/portfolio.html

I want to have a scrollable 3 x 4 grid open for a portfolio section. How can I adjust the grid content to center and be maybe 150px from the top so it will start below the header?

portfolio.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"> 
<title>Mindtale Test Home</title>
</head>

<body>




<!-- Header -->

<div id="headerlogo">
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>

<div id="headerfill"></div>
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="headerlink1">

<a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
</div>

<div id="headerlink2">
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>


<!-- Content -->

<div id="portfolio-grid">

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">BBC News</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">http://news.bbc.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">A popular destination for up-to-date news in the UK and around the World.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">EnviroGadget</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">http://www.envirogadget.com</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">One of Dan's websites focusing on the best of eco-friendly gadgets.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">http://www.google.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">The search engine that most people use.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">BBC News</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">http://news.bbc.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">A popular destination for up-to-date news in the UK and around the World.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">EnviroGadget</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">http://www.envirogadget.com</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">One of Dan's websites focusing on the best of eco-friendly gadgets.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">http://www.google.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">The search engine that most people use.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">BBC News</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">http://news.bbc.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">A popular destination for up-to-date news in the UK and around the World.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">EnviroGadget</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">http://www.envirogadget.com</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">One of Dan's websites focusing on the best of eco-friendly gadgets.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">http://www.google.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">The search engine that most people use.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">BBC News</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">http://news.bbc.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">A popular destination for up-to-date news in the UK and around the World.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">EnviroGadget</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.envirogadget.com" target="_blank">http://www.envirogadget.com</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">One of Dan's websites focusing on the best of eco-friendly gadgets.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-website">
    <div class="website-thumbnail"><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/gridimg1.png" alt="BBC News"></a></div>
    <div class="website-name"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">Google</a></div>
    <div class="website-url"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">http://www.google.co.uk</a></div>
    <div class="website-description">The search engine that most people use.</div>
    <div class="website-clear"></div>
</div>






<!-- <div id="content">
<h2>A random heading</h2>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>
<p>Content Placeholder ... </p>

</div> -->

<!-- Footer -->

<div id="footer">
Mindtale &copy; 2013
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html { 
height:100%; /* fix height to 100% for IE */
max-height:100%; /* fix height for other browsers */
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /* add background image */
-webkit-background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
-moz-background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
-o-background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
background-size: cover; /* fix height for other browsers */
}

/* Header */
/* -------------------------------------------------- */



div#header {
z-index:3;
position:fixed;
background: url(images/header.png) no-repeat center;
height: 102px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerfill {
z-index:4;
position:fixed;
background: url(images/headerfill.png) repeat-x;
height: 98px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlink1 {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size:90%;
z-index:4;
position:fixed;
top:55px;
left:18%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlink2 {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size:90%;
z-index:4;
position:fixed;
top:55px;
left:78%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlogo {
z-index:5;
position:fixed;
top:30px;
left:42%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

/* Content */
/* -------------------------------------------------- */

div#content {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
color:#222;
top: 70px; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0;
padding: 25px;
overflow: auto;



font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;

}


/* Footer */
/* -------------------------------------------------- */

div#footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
color:#999;
background:#333;
padding: 8px;
}
```

style2.css

```
/* Grid Example */
#portfolio-grid .portfolio-website {
width: 300px;
float: left;
height: 245px;
border: 1px solid #BAD4E3;
background: #E3EAF2;
text-align: left;
margin: 15px;
}
#portfolio-grid .website-description {
text-align: left;
}
#portfolio-grid .website-name {
font-size: 10pt;
}
#portfolio-grid .website-url {
display: none;
}
#portfolio-grid .website-thumbnail {
float: none;
text-align: center;
margin: 3px auto 10px;
}
#portfolio-grid .footer {
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using floats, you have to make the containers `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` in order to have them fit their children. Then, use `margin: 0 auto` to center it. I've noticed you've already put a `top: 300px` on `#gridcontainer` - in order for this to take effect, you must set the `position` attritube. Here, I've set it to `relative` since you still need to rely on the automatic margins:

```
#gridcontainer {
    top: 150px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 996px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to rethink the use of CSS floats. I'm not sure why you're float that entire `#portfolio-grid` container but you'd be better served by setting an explicit width on it (width: 1024px; might be a good starting point) and then setting the left and right margins to auto. This will center your container.

Example:

```
#portfolio-grid {
  margin: 25px auto;
}
```

This is shorthand CSS for the margin property that says to set the top and bottom margins to 25px then set the left and right margins to `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#portfolio-grid{
   margin: 100px auto 0;
    width: 998px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes using `display:inline-block` is more suitable than `float`, try this:

```
#portfolio-grid {
padding:150px 0 80px;
 text-align:center;
}

#portfolio-grid .portfolio-website {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E3EAF2;
    border: 1px solid #BAD4E3;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 245px;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 300px;
}
```

( the padding on `#portfolio-grid` is optional )